# deleting item from a ViewHolder (list), updating screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a ViewHolder that holds (relative layout) views added to a list.  In each individual layout, I have a delete button.  I want to be able to click the delete button and update the screen.  My current implementation works, but I have to hit the back button, then go back to the screen to see that is has deleted.

In essence, this is a Shopping Cart where the items are dynamically added. So in short, what do I need to add to the onClick event that will update the screen when the delete button is clicked?  Invalidate() doesn't work.

reminder: these methods separate from onCreate() so I can't use finish() or getIntent() or anything of the such.

edit: I've added additional comments to Reinier's answer

Comment: have you tried notifydatasetchanged()?

Comment: you need to use a listview, with a listadapter, and manipulate the data that back your adapter (direct methods exist on an ArrayAdapter), and use notifyDatasetChanged on the adapter to refreshthe view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using a ListView with a custom ListAdapter? Pass your dataset (e.g. an ArrayList) to your ListAdapter in the constructor. Then, when you manipulate your dataset (e.g. by `dataset.remove(Object object)`), call `.notifyDatasetChanged()` on your ListAdapter. Your adapter will then update the view it belongs to.

## Update

I'm not really sure what you mean by 'it screws up the position in the holder'. The ViewHolder is meant to basically just hold references to the `View`s you want to manipulate in your `getView()`-method. Your dataset is seperate from your ViewHolder, so removing stuff from your dataset should not affect the layout - except for removing the item from the listview, ofcourse.

Here's an example of what should work. I tried to explain as much as possible. You might know most of this but I just put some extra info down for future reference/Googlers.

Note: it's probably not perfect, but it should do just fine.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CartItem> {

// This is our data-model.
// let's say your cartitems only contain an id and name
// normally this would be defined elsewhere in your code
public class CartItem {
    public int id;
    public String product_name;
}

/*
 * ViewHolders are basically meant to keep a reference to the Views,
 * so that you don't have to use .findViewById() on every getView()
 * for the elements you're trying to manipulate.
 * 
 * .findViewById() finds Views by traversing the hierarchy (heavy).
 * This generally isn't a problem, but we want to avoid this in
 * ListViews because getView() gets called a lot - which makes our app slow.   
 * 
 * We will want to keep a reference to our TextView and Button,
 * because these are the elements we want to change every getView().
 * Not to the RelativeLayout, because it's already passed in convertView
 * (after you inflated it for the first time) and we're not manipulating it
 * anyway.
 */
public class ViewHolder {

    public Button deleteButton;
    public TextView mTextView;

}

public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems) {

    // here, we tie our data (ArrayList of CartItem's)
    // to the ListAdapter (ArrayAdapter = extended ListAdapter)
    super(context, textViewResourceId, cartItems);
}


    // this method 
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    // if convertView == null, that means we haven't inflated our listitem yet.
    if(convertView == null) {

        // so, we'll inflate our listitem now.
        // after this, convertView will contain our RelativeLayout
        // and its children/subviews
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

        // now we're gonna instantiate the ViewHolder to keep a reference
        // to our TextView and ImageView
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listitem_textview);
        holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listitem_deletebutton);

        // Now that we have our reference, we want to make sure we can
        // keep our reference by using tags. Tags are a way to attach
        // data to a View.
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // if we have already inflated our listitem, we just get the
        // references to our Views from the tag
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // we want to read/do-stuff-with a specific CartItem. First, get
    // a reference to the data-object.
    final CartItem mCartItem = (CartItem) getItem(position);

    // now, it's time to manipulate our views
    holder.mTextView.setText(mCartItem.product_name);
    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // then, pass a signal to MyAdapter that we want to remove
            // this item from our dataset
            remove(mCartItem);
            // now, we want to update any (list)views attached to our MyAdapter
            // this will let the ListView update itself
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });

    // convertView will be recycled, which means what we output here
    // will be the input for the next getView()-call
    return convertView;
}
}
```

If you want to manipulate your dataset from your activity, do the following:

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cartItems);
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);

cartItems.remove(object);
myAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

This will remove the item from the listview and yes, this will reset the position indexes. However, if you set-up your ListAdapter right, this won't be a problem.

Comment: When I do this, it works for one of the deletes. Then when I click another button, it crashes with an index out of bounds on my ArrayList. So, when debugging, I added two items to the list.  Then deleted the first item, so the second item moved up in the list to the first position.  Then when I try to delete the only remaining item, it crashes. Here is the code on my onClick for the delete buttons. (I tried Changed() and Invalidate())
`holder.buttonLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {  
public void onClick(View v)
{
cartItems.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();}});`

Comment: Through further debugging. I found the dataSet.remove(); removes from the ArrayList and moves all the elements to fill the empty space. Well that screws up the position that was set in the holder. So it's trying to delete the old position that was set. Anyway to prevent this?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. I'm not really sure what issue you're facing, but I'm thinking it has something to do with mixing your dataset and ViewHolder. I hope it's useful!

Comment: This works, I was adding one small part that was giving me problems.